# Pattern must succeed if only one slash is at the beginning

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Is there something wrong with this pattern?

Must not Match

```
re.search('^/',"//abc"):
print"/------"
```

Must Match

```
re.search('^/',"/abc"):
print"//------"
```

Comment: In both cases your pattern is "beginning of line, slash". Both of your test strings have a slash at the beginning of the line which is why they both match. Are you asking how to match "/..." but not "//..."? In other words, "slash, followed by anything other than slash"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to match one `/` at the start:

```
re.search('^/[^/]',"//abc")
```

`^/[^/]'` will match a string starting with a `/` but only if the `/` is not followed by another `/`, `^` inside the `[]` negates the match so if you wanted to ignore more than one character say either a `/` or `?`[ you would create the set `[^/?]` so both`"/?abc"` and `"//abc"` would not match.

You are matching any string starting with a `/` so logically it matches both.

If you want to get the whole string and not just see if you get a match:

```
re.search('^/[^/].*',"/abc")
```

If you want a more specific match add whatever you want after `[^/]`

Answer (score 2):

Easiest is to negate / on the 2nd character. Note:  the meaning of ^ as you had it is "at start of string".  In a character range [...] it means except those characters.

```
import re
for s in ["//abc","/abc"]:
    #[^/] will match anything not a '/'
    pat = "^/[^/]"
    hit = re.search(pat, s)
    print "search(%s, %s)=>%s" % (pat,s,bool(hit))
```

output:

```
search(^/[^/], //abc)=>False
search(^/[^/], /abc)=>True
```